# How to lock position of physic body in z axis in Unity 3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am developing a 2.5D game. In that game I want my character (which has Rigidbody component attached to) to just move on x and y axises. So I use this code snippet:

```
private void LockZAxis () {
    Vector3 currentPosition = _rigidbody.position;
    currentPosition.z = 0;
    _rigidbody.position = currentPosition;
}
```

I call this LockZAxis method in the end of both Update, FixedUpdate and LateUpdate. But it doesn't work. When my character run forward for a while, its z position is still changed.

For additional information, in my code, there are two times I manipulate the position of RegidBody. The first is when my character jump, that time I use this:

```
jumpVelocityVector = Vector3.up * jumpForceUp + transform.forward * jumpForceForward;
_rigidbody.velocity = jumpVelocityVector;
```

And each frame when I want my character to move a bit faster, so in the update method, I have this:

```
void Update () {
    Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    newPosition.z = 0;
    _rigidbody.MovePosition (newPosition);

    LockZAxis ();
}
```

Comment: I'd love to expand my answer but for that I'll need more of your code. Please add the code to where you manipulate the objects position, and why you need a rigidbody when you're setting the position each frame.

Comment: For my code. There are two times I manipulate the position of RegidBody. That is when my character jump, that time I use this: 
_rigidbody.velocity = Vector3.up * jumpForceUp + transform.forward * jumpForceForward; 

And each frame when I want my character to move a bit faster, so in the update method, I have this:
Vector3 newPosition = transform.position + transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
newPosition.z = 0;
_rigidbody.MovePosition (newPosition);

LockZAxis ();

Comment: Have you check if your animation has some root motion? If so this may be the cause of your y position changing overtime.

Comment: @Kardux yeah, I am actually applying root animation. And the root animation does not have ability to lock z position independently with x position. I still want to apply root animation and let animation move my objects on x and y axis.

Answer (score 1):

A rigidbody is used to simulate physics, by setting the rigidbody's position every frame you're essentially teleporting the character every frame. You can restrict movement in z-axis, this will prevent it to move in z-axis when physics is applied, which is what a rigidbody typically is used for.

Here is how to restrict rigidbody positional change:

[image: Here is how to restrict rigidbody positional change]

If you run your `LockZAxis()` *after* you've changed the position it should teleport the object to the z-position of 0 every frame. Please make sure that the z-axis is the correct axis. You can debug this by pausing a running game and manipulating the Transform values to see how each axis moves your Object.

Comment: I have set the Freeze Position Z too, but it still doesn't work. After run for a while, its z position is going far from 0 and then it cannot collide with colliders that has z = 0.

Comment: As mentioned, it wont work when you're "teleporting" the objects. Rigidbody is used with physics and the restrictions are for the physics. Also, please see my comment on your question.

Comment: Yeah, I have also replied to your comment. Please see. So what should I do, doe MovePosition can help in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**Here is how you can do it with C# Script:**

*Freeze All Positions*

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition;
```

*Freeze Specific Positions:*

```
rigidbody.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionZ;
```

[Unity Documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePosition.html)

Answer (score 0):

Is physics gravity set to only affect the Y position ?
 `Physics.gravity = new Vector3(0, -1.0F, 0);`

And set these also 
`rigidbody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;`
 `rigidbody.velocity.z=0;`

make sure your rigidbody is set to kinematic since you are using Rigidbody.moveposition() and  using moveposition() will directly effect velocity internally on a kinematic rigidbody

Try using moveposition() for you jump instead of velocity

Comment: Hi. Changing Regidbody.position is a recommended way by official Unity document for implement jumping. You can check it here (https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html). And yes, I have setup the gravity to only affect Y position for sure. I don't think that I need to set Rigibody to kinematic to use MovePosition, do you have any reference links for this?

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html.   "If the rigidbody has isKinematic set false then it works differently. It works like transform.position=newPosition and teleports the object (rather than a smooth transition)."  Teleporting the object can cause some issue with physics